# Symfony 5 - Prevent user from logging out after time

Tags: symfony, session

According to documentation:

> There are often circumstances where you may want to protect, or
> minimize unauthorized use of a session when a user steps away from
> their terminal while logged in by destroying the session after a
> certain period of idle time. For example, it is common for banking
> applications to log the user out after just 5 to 10 minutes of
> inactivity. Setting the cookie lifetime here is not appropriate
> because that can be manipulated by the client, so we must do the
> expiry on the server side. The easiest way is to implement this via
> garbage collection which runs reasonably frequently. The
> cookie_lifetime would be set to a relatively high value

> Setting a cookie_lifetime to 0 will cause the cookie to live only as long as the browser remains open.

I didn't mess up with garbage collector but I've tried to add `cookie_lifetime` in session configuration:

**framework.yaml**

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 0
```

It didn't help.

I've tried inheritance:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

class MySessionTime extends NativeSessionStorage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(['cookie_lifetime' => "0"]);
    }
}
```

It didn't help.
Clearing Symfony cache also didn't help.

My users are getting automatically log out every few minutes.
I want my application to keep users logged in as long as their session is alive.

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** this happens? How long does that cookie last? Which lifetime for PHP sessions did you configure?

Comment: It has nothing to do with cookies because Symfony should store such informations in session on server side. Then garbage collector clears that session value/values based on its configuration. I'll check that config values (gc_probability, gc_divisor and gc_maxlifetime).
`If the garbage collection handler is invoked, PHP will pass the value stored in the php.ini directive session.gc_maxlifetime. The meaning in this context is that any stored session that was saved more than gc_maxlifetime ago should be deleted. This allows one to expire records based on idle time.`

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that a PHP session can work in any way without cookies?

Comment: Really?
"Session" is a shortcut of "session cookie".
"Cookie" is a phrase commonly used in client side environment.
"Session" or "session cookie" is a phrase commonly used in server side environment.
You meant "session" but you said "cookie". Not my fault.

Comment: "How long does that cookie last" is a pretty clear question relating to the session cookie, and the lifetime of sessions itself (server-side) is also affected unless you refresh the lifetime on each request. Please don't be rude to people who try to help you

Answer (score -1):

I suggest another approach.
Create a service and add yourself the time you want to disconnect the user after X min if there were no requests.

i would do like this :

```
class LogoutIfInactiveListener{

private SessionInterface $session;
private RouterInterface $router;
private TokenStorageInterface $token;
private int $maxIdleTime = 0;

public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, RouterInterface $router, TokenStorageInterface $token, int $maxIdleTime)
{
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->maxIdleTime = $maxIdleTime;
}

public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->maxIdleTime > 0) {

        $this->session->start();
        $lapse = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();

        if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_logout')));
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to use it in your service.yml. To go further you can even use a setTimeOut in JS to refresh the page automatically

Comment: This won't help if the root cause is unknown

Comment: This will not prevent Symfony from checking exactly the same thing and logging out the user. Your code only checks if YOUR idle time fires and after that Symfony garbage collector is doing its own anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong but your listener doesn't override Symfonys behavior.